# TypeError: $(...).on is not a function in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I trying to fetch data from database when corresponds to the value of the drop down selected,now i am getting an error:

```
TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

$("#country").on("change", function() {
```

My code:

```
<htm>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery 1.7.js"></script>

   <script>
$(function() {  //  document.ready
    $("#country").on("change", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "country.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                country: $(this).val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#results").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<form name="welcomeDiv1" id="welcomeDiv1">
<tr class="unsortable" >

<select name="country" id="country" > 
   <option value="">Select Country</option>
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbDatabase = 'priceflag';

$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `country` FROM 9xx");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{

            print' <option id="country" name="country" value="'.$row['country'].'" >'.$row['country'].' </option>';


   }  
   ?>  
</select>  
 </tr>
 </form>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

can anyone guide me how to fix this error

Comment: js is not included properly please check you have included jquery library once this page or try to use jQuery

Comment: Why 3 versions of jQuery?

Comment: do you have any of the said 3 jQuery files in the path

Answer (score 3):

You are loading 3 versions of jQuery. 
The latest one might be obsolete, and
may not have "on" method.
Use only 1 version, and try to go for a latest versio e.g. 1.9

```
<script src="js/jquery 1.7.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the actual jQuery version that loaded to the page (if any), the .on() method doesn't exist. I would go for a newest jquery available (2.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the error occur because of different version of jquery ,if you are using multiple jquery files in your application then you can use [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) 
function to get the appropriate Output.
Hope this Helps.